Powershell open 2 specific urls on different monitors
I have a surface laptop 5 that I use with a dock to connect it to 3 monitors. I have a main widescreen and then 2 27" monitors on top. I want to open a specific url on the top left monitor and another on the top right at startup. I couldn't find a way to do this so tried to make a powershell script that I can run to do this at least. The script is opening both url windows on the top right monitor when I need one to be on the top left. I can't figure this out please help.
```
# Define URLs 
$url1 = "https://www.twitter.com"
$url2 = "https://www.gmail.com"

# Load necessary assemblies
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

# Get the working area for each monitor
$screen1 = [System.Windows.Forms.Screen]::AllScreens[0].WorkingArea
$screen2 = [System.Windows.Forms.Screen]::AllScreens[1].WorkingArea

# Calculate the center of each monitor
$center1X = $screen1.Left + $screen1.Width / 2
$center1Y = $screen1.Top + $screen1.Height / 2
$center2X = $screen2.Left + $screen2.Width / 2
$center2Y = $screen2.Top + $screen2.Height / 2

# Start the browser processes and position the windows
Start-Process "msedge" -ArgumentList "--new-window", "--window-position=$($center1X-    960),$($center1Y-540)", $url1
Start-Process "msedge" -ArgumentList "--new-window", "--window-position=$($center2X-   960),$($center2Y-540)", $url2`

```

